# How to naturally express the idea "quelqu'un d'aussi avisé qu'expérimenté que vous"

Tags: expressions

> My try: Il faut avoir l'avis de **quelqu'un d'aussi avisé qu'expérimenté que vous**.

I’m stuck on how to express the idea:

> someone as wise and experienced as you
>
> OR more literally: someone as wise as they are experienced (as you)

because two different ideas are involved and compared here:

> quelqu'un d'aussi avisé qu'expérimenté
>
> AND: quelqu'un d'aussi avisé{expérimenté} que vous

I’m not sure how to get around this duality problem and express the idea naturally in French. I think that my sentence needs some improvement.

---

**UPDATE:**

The use of "**et**" between "avisé" and "expérimenté" would solve the problem nicely. What I want to find out here, though: What if you start your sentence saying "quelqu'un d'aussi avisé **qu**'expérimenté" and then need to add the second idea "quelqu'un d'aussi avisé{expérimenté} **que vous**" as an afterthought? Using two "que"s like this sounds clumsy, I suppose.

Comment: Why do you want to use "que" ? You said in english "someone as wise **and** experienced as you", which implies an "et", which would be fine in french. Personnaly, I wouldn't understand your 2nd english sentence: "someone as wise as they are experienced as you". Is this structure natural in english ?

Comment: @R: Yes, the use of "et" would solve the problem nicely. What I want to find out here, though: What if you start your sentence saying "quelqu'un d'aussi avisé qu'expérimenté" and then need to add the second idea "quelqu'un d'aussi avisé que vous" as an afterthought? Using two "que"s like this sounds clumsy, I suppose. Merci.

Comment: @R: On a side note, regarding my phrasing "someone as wise as they are experienced (as you)", I used this phrase solely for the purpose of providing a literal translation. So it doesn't sound natural, but this structure does exists. You might want to check out the following page for further details. Merci. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105634/as-as-vs-as-much-as

Comment: Your first comment is interesting, I think you should add it to your question ;)

Comment: On your 2nd comment, what makes it sound odd is the 3rd "as", and the use of "as they are experienced". I would have written "someone as wise as experimented", but since i'm not that good in english, I must be wrong...

Comment: @Luna I'm a native English speaker. "Luna is as wise as she is experienced" is a perfectly fine sentence and doesn't sound unnatural (to me). However, "Luna is as wise as she is experienced as you" sounds incorrect, and the cited EL&U question doesn't seem to indicate otherwise.

Comment: @a: Yes. This cumbersome phrasing (... as you) was solely for the sake of deliberately providing a literal translation. The referenced page is for elaborating on the part "someone (is) as wise as they are experienced", which I thought Random was  asking about. Looks like my previous comment wasn't clear enough. Merci.

Comment: Is  the “as” in “as you” in the second, more literal English version serving to mean “**like** /[as you are yourself]” to refer back to both previously mentioned [equal] qualities (“equally wise and experienced[, as you yourself are]”)  or is it (as I think is the case based on your update)  serving as a second comparison marker referring “you” only back to “wise” (in series with the first “as [experienced]” which is more clearly marking a comparison back to “wise”)?

Comment: @P: I intended "que vous" to refer to both qualities{adjectives}. I chose to include just one of them in my post for simplicity to make my point clearer.

Comment: In that case, maybe just changing the 2nd “que” to "comme" (and maybe the word order) in the French version would work: “… l'avis de quelqu'un [comme vous] d'aussi avisé qu'expérimenté [comme vous].

Comment: @LUNA No problem, I just wanted to make sure you were talking about the EL&U question in relation to the first sentence without the contents of the parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that "quelqu'un d'aussi avisé qu'expérimenté, tel que vous" expresses well your english sentence "someone as wise as they are experienced as you".

Comment: I'd rather translate : "someone as wise as experimented, such as you". I don't understand why "…they are experienced…" in your translation ??

Comment: @Stéphane : The user wanted a french translation for his english sentence. The part "..they are experienced..." is part of his original sentence.

Answer (score 2):

« Quelqu’un d’aussi avisé et expérimenté que vous/toi » → "someone as wise and experienced as you"

Answer (score 1):

With your update about this being added as an afterthought in mind, I think you could start with the cool notion of “someone being just as wise as they are experienced” (which, imo, goes beyond “being wise and experienced” [although please note that the comparison form **could** be used sarcastically/negatively to imply that someone’s lack of wisdom is equally matched by their lack of experience]) just as you’ve proposed (without the “que vous”) and follow it with @Stéphane 's good  “as wise **and** experienced as you” version in its entirety, which would not only avoid the "clumsy" and unclear second “que” in one phrase but it would also help clarify that you’re not being negative or sarcastic with the first phrase:

> « Il faut avoir l'avis de quelqu'un d'aussi avisé qu'expérimenté …
>   c'est-à-dire/autrement dit quelqu’un d’aussi avisé et expérimenté que
>   vous ».